# How to make subtotal for each row in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a subtotal for each products that I have. I already create the codes and it's working well, but the problem is if there are two or more products, the price will only change the first product, not the second and the rest. So, how to make it dynamically with the rest of the product? Here's my code.

```
    function priceTotal(value) {
        var grandTotal = 0;
        $('.subtotal').each(function() {
            var qty = value;
            var price = parseInt($('.price').text());
            var subTotal = value * price;
            grandTotal = grandTotal + subTotal;
            // document.getElementById("subtotal").innerText = "Rp. " + subTotal.toLocaleString('en');
            $(this).text("Rp. " + subTotal.toLocaleString('en'));
        });
        // document.getElementById("grandtotal").innerText = "Rp. " + grandTotal.toLocaleString('en');
        $('.grandtotal').text("Rp. " + grandTotal.toLocaleString('en'));
    }

    $('.increment-btn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var incre_value = $(this).parents('.quantity').find('.qty-input').val();
        var value = parseInt(incre_value, 10);
        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        if (value < 100) {
            value++;
            $(this).parents('.quantity').find('.qty-input').val(value);
        }

        priceTotal(value);
    });

    $('.decrement-btn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var decre_value = $(this).parents('.quantity').find('.qty-input').val();
        var value = parseInt(decre_value, 10);
        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        if (value > 1) {
            value--;
            $(this).parents('.quantity').find('.qty-input').val(value);
        }

        priceTotal(value);
    });
```

```
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead class="bg-transparent">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Thumbnail</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Brand</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Product</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Size</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Price</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Quantity</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Subtotal</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="text-center">Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        @foreach($cartlists as $cartlist)
                        <tbody class="bg-transparent" class="checkout_cart">
                            <tr class="cartpage">
                                <td class="text-center"><img src="{{asset('uploads/products/' . $cartlist->product->productimage)}}" width="100px;" height="100px;" alt="Image"></td>
                                <td class="text-center">{{$cartlist->product->brand->name}}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">{{$cartlist->product->productname}}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">{{$cartlist->product->productsize}}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">Rp. <span class="price" data-price="{{$cartlist->product->productprice}}">{{ $cartlist->product->productprice}}</span></td>
                                <td class="cart-product-quantity text-center" width="132px">
                                    <div class="input-group quantity">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend decrement-btn changeQuantity" style="cursor: pointer">
                                            <span class="input-group-text">-</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="text" class="qty-input form-control text-center" maxlength="2" value="1">
                                        <div class="input-group-append increment-btn changeQuantity" style="cursor: pointer">
                                            <span class="input-group-text">+</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <span class="subtotal">Rp. {{ number_format($cartlist->product->productprice)}}</span>
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <a href="/product-cart/delete/{{$cartlist->id}}" class="d-inline btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        @endforeach
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="text-left mt-3">
                    <h5 class="bold">Total: <span class="grandtotal"></span></h5>
                    <p>Delivery and discount will be calculated during the checkout process.</p>
                </div>
```

Here's the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ID` has to be unique, you have the same `id="subtotal"` in every row. Change it for class.

**JS**

```
function priceTotal(value) {
        var grandTotal = 0;
        $('.subtotal').each(function() {
      //  ^^
            var qty = value;
            var price = parseInt($("#price").text());
            var subTotal = value * price;
            grandTotal = grandTotal + subTotal;
            $(this).text("Rp. " + subTotal.toLocaleString('en'));
        //  ^^^^^^^ $(this) instead of document.getElementByid
        });
        document.getElementById("grandtotal").innerText = "Rp. " + grandTotal.toLocaleString('en');
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<td class="text-center">
    <span class="subtotal">Rp. {{ number_format($cartlist->product->productprice)}}</span>
</td>
```

The same problem will be with other IDs in your foreach loop. There are `#price` and `#qty-input`.

Comment: hi, i tried to change it with class but its not working. i edited my code above and the result when it change to class. it shows all the subtotal from two rows. please take a look on it @pavel

Comment: Sure, `parseInt($('.price').text());` is very general, you need to target `.price` in the same `TR` (now you have all `.price` elements). I answered your question, what you're now looking for is basic JS debugging (target the right element, counting with numbers vs. joining strings (both with `+`), etc.).

Comment: ah, i see.. i should target the right element in order to find each price and qty. thankyou! i already solved the problem.